# Using limit with UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select following records but using single or combination of queries

1. I want to select all records which salary is  100
2. I want to select top 50 records only of which salary is 200

I want to collect all records using single or combination of queries and display total records at once

I tried following but not working

> SELECT salary FROM ( SELECT salary FROM salaries WHERE salary= 200 limit 50 ) salaries WHERE salary= 100

Can anybody help me

Comment: `top 50 records` how can we determine that? give structure of table `salary `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM salaries WHERE salary = 100 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM salaries WHERE salary= 200 limit 50)
```

Try this one including bracket.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

`SELECT * FROM salaries WHERE salary = 100 UNION (SELECT * FROM salaries WHERE salary= 200 limit 50)`

Comment: no this is not working. i have already tried. it show only 50 records but only for salary=100

Comment: Sorry, forgot  the parenthesis - without them the limit applies to the whole union. Fixed in the edit.